# Something to collect and track data for children's meals

Tags: data, collection-manager

I work at a non-profit organization and they were paying a company that allowed them to use their program. The company is going away. The org I work with serves meals to children at different sites, some sites being churches, YMCAs, schools, etc. After the staff at these sites serve food to their kids, they have to enter how many meals they give out.

The system/software program needs to be able to have customization that allows users to depict a date and enter numbers for specific types of meals. Here is an example of things that would be collected on a daily basis for each of these sites:

- Total received (total meals to serve including delivered and
  leftovers from the day before)
- First meals (meals given out to kids as their first meal)
- Second meals (second servings of meals given out to kids)
- Incomplete meals (meals missing a component such as a fruit or milk)
- Leftovers (Total - given out & incomplete = leftovers)

Does anyone know of any programs/software like this or can help lead me toward something?

Thank you in advance for your time and help!!